# SPRESENSEのSPI2端子をGPIOとして利用することは可能か？

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSEを利用したシステム設計時のSPI2端子について教えてください。

SPRESENSEモジュールを使用した基板を検討しています。
UART0とSPI2は端子が兼用されており、system0,1端子の入力状態によって機能が切り替わるとの理解です。

SPI2用の端子(CN4 71,73,75,77)を通常のGPIOとして利用したいのですが、ソフト開発上何か問題がありますでしょうか？
ソフト書き込みはCP2102N接続のUART1で可能との理解です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPIOとして使用可能です。例えば、SPI2_MISO,MOSI(CN4 73,75)は拡張ボードの汎用コネクタにも出ていてGPIO入出力用途に普通に使えています。

起動直後はsystem0,1で機能が切り替わるみたいですが(知らなかった)、CXD5602ユーザマニュアルをみるとLATCH_OFFをたたけば機能を無効化できると書いてあり、ソースコードにもその通りの制御があるのを見付けました。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx/blob/HEAD/arch/arm/src/cxd56xx/cxd56_pinconfig.c#L379
起動後にGPIOモードに切り替えれば普通に使えそうです。
それとソフト書き込みはUART1ですし一切影響無いと思います。